# Cauchy-Kovalevsky Theorem: Application question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I'm reading [Zachmanoglou's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486652513), and I'm having trouble interpreting how they conclude that $F(t,x,u,p)$ is analytic in their example:

> **Example.** Let
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> u_t &= uu_x \\
> u(0,x) &= 1 + x^2 \tag{$\star$}.
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Use the Cauchy-Kovalevsky Theorem to find all terms $\leq 3$ in the Taylor series about the origin.

So, for a single variable function $f$, we say it is analytic about $x_0$ if

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x - x_0)^n. \tag{1}$$

Clearly, $f(x) = 1 + x^2$, is analytic about the origin.

They then state that, $F(t,x,u,p) = up$, is analytic about the the neighborhood $(0,0,1,0)$, and so we can apply C-K. But what is the Taylor series analog of $(1)$ to actually show this? I don't yet see how this is trivial?

---

**Edit 1:** I will include the C-K Theorem here for reference.

**Theorem.** *Suppose that $\phi$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that the function $F$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the point
$$(0, 0, \dots, \phi(0, \dots, 0), \phi_{x_1}(0, \dots, 0), \dots, \phi_{x_n}(0, \dots, 0))$$
of $\mathbb{R}^{2n + 2}$. Then the Cauchy problem $(\star)$ (it's really $\mathbb{R}^4$ for the example above) has a solution $u(t,x_1, \dots, x_n)$ which is defined and analytic in a neighborhood of the origin of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and this solution is unique in the class of analytic functions.*